# Strong Induction on Fibonacci's properties

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-explanation, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I need to prove by induction the following property but I keep getting stuck. i uploaded an image because I don't know how to properly format math notation here.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7AQt.png]

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  See also the MathJax reference in the cited article, and the **Edit-Images** section of the article.

Comment: @user2661923 this isn't homework. We did this in class but I was absent .

Comment: Whether it is homework or not is irrelevant.  Please follow the instructions in the cited article.  Please focus especially on MathJax, detailing the tools, detailing the problem source and your Math background, and also please show a legitimate attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @user2661923 Okok i see. Thank you for the advice. Am i allowed to take a picture of my work and upload it here ? will I get downvotes if I do this instead of typing it into the website .

Comment: Taking a picture of your work is better than nothing.  However, if you examine the MathJax link, I think that you will find that it is fairly easy to use MathJax to display the Math.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Showing your work is better than nothing, but you are not allowed to take a picture of your work and upload it. Other users who could need the same information from your work would not be able to search for it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} F_{2i} = \sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i} + F_{2(n+1)}$

Comment: Oh I see . But aren't I trying to prove this property. Why am allowed to use it in the beginning. Shouldn't I begin with the recursive formula first and then show it is equal to the sum ?

Comment: That hint is part of the induction proof. @newtocoding123